# Adding column that returns the date of latest entry given a specific subject

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I'm very new to SQL, I think this is a quick fix: Below is the current Raw SQL for the software utilized in our office.  I would like to add a column that returns the date of the latest entry in the "pronotes" table where pronotes.subject = "Patient Contact".  The column would be titled "Last Pt. Contact".  I have no idea if this is enough information, or if this is a quick fix or a big deal.  Thanking you in advance.

**EDIT** This is the  table structure.  The Primary Key for OT looks to be Orderno

**HR**

---

*MRN*

PTNAME

PTADDRESS

*ALL OTHER FIELDS**

---

**PRONOTES**

---

MRN

SUBJECT

DATE_

BODY

*ALL OTHER FIELDS

---

**OT**

---

ORDERS NO

MRN

*ALL OTHER FIELDS

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN OT.STAT=1 THEN 'STAT' ELSE '    ' END AS 'STAT', 
HR.LAST_NAME AS 'LAST_NAME', 
HR.FIRST_NAME AS 'FIRST_NAME',
HR.REFERRAL AS 'REFERRAL_SOURCE',
HR.PHONE AS 'PHONE', 
OT.ORDERED AS 'ORDERED', 
OT.DESCRIP AS 'DESCRIP', 
PTSHIP.SH_ADDR AS 'SH_ADDR', 
CASE WHEN OT.INSNO=99999 THEN 'PATIENT' ELSE INSCOMP.ORG END AS 'ORG', 
OT.INUSE AS 'INUSE', 
OT.TICKINFONO AS 'TICKINFONO', 
OT.NO AS 'NO', 
OT.MRN AS 'MRN', 
LABELS.SCRIPTEXT AS 'SCRIPTEXT',
labels.cpk_labels,
HR.SSN,
OT.ENTSTATUSCHANGED,    
P_ENTSTATUS.INITIALS AS ENTSTATUSBY, 
POP_ENTSTATUS.TEXT_ AS ENTSTATUS,
dbo.f_GetLastEligCheckDate(hr.cpk_hr,ot.insno) as lastcheck,
dbo.f_GetPrimaryPhone(hr.cpk_hr) as PrimaryPhone,
POP_LASTEVENT.TEXT_ AS LASTEVENT
FROM OT
INNER JOIN HR ON HR.DELFLAG = 0 AND HR.MRN = OT.MRN
LEFT JOIN LABELS ON LABELS.DELFLAG = 0 AND LABELS.ORDERNO = OT.NO
LEFT JOIN INSCOMP ON INSCOMP.DELFLAG = 0 AND INSCOMP.NO = OT.INSNO
LEFT JOIN PTSHIP ON PTSHIP.DELFLAG = 0 AND PTSHIP.MRN = OT.MRN
LEFT JOIN POPUPDATA POP_ENTSTATUS ON POP_ENTSTATUS.DELFLAG = 0 AND POP_ENTSTATUS.CPK_POPUPDATA = OT.CFK_POPUPDATA_ENTSTATUS
LEFT JOIN PNNAMES P_ENTSTATUS ON P_ENTSTATUS.DELFLAG = 0 AND P_ENTSTATUS.NO = OT.CFK_PNNAMES_ENTSTATUS
LEFT JOIN POPUPDATA POP_LASTEVENT ON POP_LASTEVENT.DELFLAG = 0 AND POP_LASTEVENT.CPK_POPUPDATA = OT.CFK_POPUPDATA_ENTSTATUS_LASTEVENT
WHERE OT.DELFLAG = 0 AND
OT.LISTID = 'H-NEWORDER' AND
OT.DRUG = 0 AND
OT.THERAPY = 1
```

Comment: This pronotes table does it relate anyhow to the other tables. To the HR table perhaps? What I meant is you want to find latest "patient contact" so there must be a patient id and a date in the table. Maybe you can just post the structure of the table so we can have a look.

Comment: hr.mrn is the patient Id system wide.  pronotes.mrn & ot.mrn = hr.mrn. The tables Pronotes and OT do not have any direct relationships, but the *.mrn values are the same.  I'm still waiting for a visual for table structure.

Comment: added table structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find latest date a patient. I would suggest you do that in a sub-query which you join to in your main query.

```
SELECT
  ...
  LastPatientContact.Date as 'Last Pt. Contact'
FROM OT
  ...
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT MRN, MAX(date) as Date
  FROM pronotes
  WHERE subject = 'Patient Contact'
  GROUP BY MRN
) LastPatientContact
  ON LastPatientContact.MRN = OT.MRN
```

Comment: THANKS A LOT ! WORKED PERFECTLY!